# json called hindered by Access- Control-Allow -Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I should make a json call with javascript:

```
var arr = { username: "user@user.com", password : "mypassword" , portfolioID : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://siam.eseye.com/login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

the error that comes back to me : CORS header " Access- Control-Allow -Origin " missing .
Attention, before saying that it is a double question , read here , I searched online and I did :

1. inserted header ( " Access- Control-Allow -Origin : * " ) ;
2. Wamp > Apache > Apache Modules > headers_module enabled
3. added the datatype
4. dataType: json or jsonp the error remain

after all of this evidence , it will not work the same .

Is there anything else I forgot to try?
with Postman the API work.

Thank you.

Comment: No! You have not added the datatype.

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet where you set the headers?

Comment: Where did you add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` headers? Make sure your ajax request to `https://siam.eseye.com/login` contains `Origin` header as well.

Comment: Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use  `dataType: "jsonp"` which is use for cross site scripting.Check [**here**](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) for more about jsonp

I created this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/y9h0dup1/1/). The request semms to be served but the response have error. You can validate it console in developer's tool

Comment: Not an answer. More like a comment

Comment: @Jai _the error that comes back to me : CORS header " Access- Control-Allow -Origin " missing_. I think I have answered that and to get proper response it may need proper username, password and portfolioID  which the user has not provided. Probably that is the reason of error in response. Otherwise I think i have addresses the issue of CORS

Comment: request is redirected to error page, the request itself seems to work

Comment: i can't use jsonp from directive api

Comment: @Mr.Developer sorry I dont understand what is directive api. `dataType` is just another configuration key of ajax. I think if you are using ajax you can also set the key. Check the jsfiddle

Comment: i receive this error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 

"status":{

Comment: supplier of my API does not allow to do jsonp calls but only as json datatype

Comment: @Mr.Developer probably that issue with the response but I guess you are no more facing CORS